# How to run webjobs in azure emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a console based application as WebJob. Now internally i am trying to map a CloudDrive using the storageconnectionstring `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`

It is throwing exception `ERROR_AZURE_DRIVE_DEV_PATH_NOT_SET`. I searched for this error and found that WebJobs do not run locally in Azure emulator. Is this information still valid?
Is there any plan to provide emulator (storage) support for webjobs in near future say in a week or so?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The information is still valid - we don't support the Azure emulator.

We have that work item on our backlog but I cannot give you any ETA.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Boo hoo Microsoft... This seems rather stupid given that you want us to start adopting the use of Azure Web Jobs!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are new few lines of code in current version, which I believe solves this issue

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```